# Deserialize coordinate string into geometry instance in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, geometry

I want to serialize a System.Windows.Media.Geometry Object into something like *"F1M50;50L200;50 200;250 50;250 50;50z"* (I got this by using GetOutlinedPathGeometry()) and deserialize it later by using this string.
Geometry.Parse doesn't seem to be the right way to do this. I think it cannot handle the format the string is in.

**Is there a way in c# to get a Geometry Object out of this string: *"F1M50;50L200;50 200;250 50;250 50;50z"* ?**

Comment: A workaround is to replace the ";" with ","